# Having two div over another one and still wrapping text

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm looking for a way to have two div over another one but without the text going under or over the floating div. What I mean by that is when the text from the `<div class="text"></div>` element is reaching `<div class="barcode"></div>` or `<div class="uniq_barcode"></div>`, I don't want the text to wrap on another line instead of going under the div. [Here's an image with the div I'm trying to create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq6kQ.jpg)

I've tried to use `<img>` tag with `align:right` but it doesn't work for the second div. I think `flexbox` or `grid` would do the trick, but I'm not strong enough with those thing.

My code look this way and can actually be changed:

```
<div class="custom-container">
    <div class="barcode"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="uniq_barcode"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS look like that:

```
.barcode, .uniq_barcode {
    width: 300px,
    height: 300px
}
```

The only thing I really need is the `<dev class="text"></div>` element for my text.

Thanks you.

Comment: where is your css?

Comment: Here I added my CSS but since I don't know how to make it work, I don't have much more.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the structure of your HTML code, a first try would be the following CSS (not optimized). However, as @Kerri suggests, it'd be better to use flexbox in your case.

```
.custom-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.text,
.barcode,
.uniq_barcode{
  position: absolute;
}

.text{
 top:0;
 left:0;
 border: 5px solid red;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.barcode,
.uniq_barcode{
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.barcode{
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
 }
.uniq_barcode{
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

You can test the code at this link: https://jsfiddle.net/8vrwto16/1/

Comment: That's a good solution for positioning the div, but the text from `<div class="text"></div>` still going over the two other div. I need to figure a way to make text going on another line if it's reaching the div.

Comment: Indeed my solution is a workaround, you should definitely structure differently your HTML and use grid or flex to get better and more responsive results.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `grid` and `flex` were developed for just this sort of layout. This seems like a job for flexbox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox